# Swift 1.2 [AnyObject] does not have member named 'objectForKey'

Tags: swift

After upgrading to Swift 1.2, I got an error:

```
[AnyObject] does not have member named 'objectForKey'
```

Code:

```
self.photoNames = objects.map { $0.objectForKey("PhotoName") as! String }
```

Where `objects` is type `[AnyObject]`

#### Edit: (more code)

```
var photoNames: [String] = []
var query = PFQuery(className: "Photos")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({(objects:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
    if(error == nil){
        self.photoNames = objects.map { $0.objectForKey("PhotoName") as! String }
    }
    else{
        println("Error in retrieving \(error)")
    }
        
})
```

Comment: You should downcast AnyObject to NSDictionary

Comment: @ArtSabintsev i get the error "cast from [AnyObject] to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails

Comment: Don't cast the entire array, just the item inside the array. AnyObject downcasted to NSDictionary.

Comment: @ArtSabintsev like in the answer below? I tried, but still ran into the error that the cast always fails http://i.imgur.com/YvazMar.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that `objects` is an array of dictionaries. The thing to do is to prove it. Where you have this:

```
if(error == nil){
    self.photoNames = objects.map { $0.objectForKey("PhotoName") as! String }
}
```

Put this:

```
if error == nil {
    if let objects = objects as? [[NSObject:AnyObject]] {
        self.photoNames = objects.map {$0["PhotoName"] as! String}
    }
}
```

There is still some danger - you will crash if one of the dictionaries does not have a "PhotoName" key or if that key's value is not a string - but at least the above should *compile*. We can always add more safety checks later.

Comment: Thanks Matt, but the above code does not compile for me: http://i.imgur.com/uLK4phl.png

Comment: Because I left out a pair of square brackets! :( Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

`objectForKey:` is a member method of `NSDictionary`, not `AnyObject`. Here is the [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectForKey:).

If the `objects` is array of `NSDictionary`, try this:

```
self.photoNames = objects?.map { ($0 as? NSDictionary)?.objectForKey("PhotoName") as! String } ?? []
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but it is still not working with your answer. http://i.imgur.com/YvazMar.png

Comment: And i get the error "cast from [AnyObject] to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails

Comment: Can you post more code of  objects and photoNames variable

Comment: I update the answer, the objects is optional, so you need to add '?' before map(). And photoName is not optional, so you need to '??' convert nil result as empty array